# Same method,seemingly same String string input, different results

Tags: java, spring

I am working on an application with multitenancy (new to java/spring), trying to get connected to different databases with different users. Got some weird experiences with the java.lang.String class

When using  String string as a @PathVariable, it is working - method(pathvariable).
If i define the argument in a hard-coded way, without using PathVariables, it is working - method("string").

But when i try to define a String string with my code, without using PathVariables, it is not working - get a string from db based on user data and use the result with the method(string) to change the db connection.

I have added some log info as well but still, it all seems to be the same but still cant make this work. Is it has to do something with code execution order, controller lifecycle, variable types?

```
tenantContext

public class TenantContext {

    private static ThreadLocal<String> currentTenant = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setCurrentTenant(String tenant) {

        currentTenant.set(tenant);

    }

    public static String getCurrentTenant() {
        return currentTenant.get();
    }

    public static void clear() {
        currentTenant.set(null);
    }
}


* PROBLEMATIC SOLUTION **********************************************

@GetMapping("/koms-list/name-containing")
public List<Kom> komsListByNameContaining(
               Principal principal,
               User user,
               @RequestParam("targetKomName") String targetKomName
           )                
    {

    user = userRepository.findByUsername(principal.getName());
    String dbContext = new String();
    dbContext = user.getClient_db();

        TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(dbContext);//NOT WORKING
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenant("whatever");// THIS WORKS

        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());
        logger.info("Client db name based on Principal > " + user.getClient_db());
        logger.info("Client db name variable-data type > " + user.getClient_db().getClass().getName());

        logger.info("Active users name based on Principal > " + principal.getName());
        logger.info("TenantContext variable data type > " + dbContext.getClass().getName());

        logger.info("TenantContext variable value > " + dbContext);
        logger.info("Target kom to find > " + targetKomName);

        List<Kom> result = komRepository.findByNevContaining(targetKomName);

        return result;

    * WORKING SOLUTION **************************************************

        @GetMapping("/koms-list/selected-client/{client}/selected-partner/{sif}")
                public List<Kom> komListBySif(
                        @PathVariable (value = "sif") Long sif,
                        @PathVariable (value = "client") String client
                        )
        {
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(client);// THIS WORKS AS WELL        
        List<Kom> kom = (List<Kom>) komRepository.findBySif(sif);
        return kom;
        }
```

I would expect that String dbContext = user.getClient_db() string could be used just as Pathvariable String client. But they dont work out the same result. Did i miss some basic java thingie here?

*** more code ***

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;

public class MultitenantDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    @Override
    public Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
    }
}
```

is this a proper way of changing db connections, via loading application.properties from different files/folders, based on user data?

*** UPDATE ***

```
/**
         * SECOND CONTROLLER
         * get selected KOM by sif
         * 
         *  */
        @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000/partners")
        @GetMapping("/koms-list/selected-client/{client}/selected-partner/{sif}")
        public List<Kom> komListBySif(
                @PathVariable (value = "sif") Long sif,
                @PathVariable (value = "client") String client
                )
        {
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

            String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();

            User user = userRepository.findByUsername(currentPrincipalName);

            String context = user.getClient_db();

            context = Normalizer.normalize(context, Form.NFD);

            Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());
            logger.info("Client db name based on pathVariable > " + client);
            logger.info("TenantContext variable data type based on context > " + context.getClass().getName());
            //TenantContext tenantContext = new TenantContext();
            //TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(client);
            TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(client);

            List<Kom> kom = (List<Kom>) komRepository.findBySif(sif);

            return kom;
        }
```

// succesfully broken too, cant change to another db connection

Comment: `String dbContext = new String();` What is the purpose of this line in your code?

Comment: Thank you for your time Nikhil. That is just a miserable act from me to try and force a result that could be handled as a proper argument of the setCurrentTenant method. `String dbContext = user.getClient_db();` leads to the same result, no difference, tryed before. Any further idea?

Comment: If i input "manually" the argument, as like `TenantContext.setCurrentTenant("whatever");` it works. But if i try to use `TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(dbContext);` it is not working. i have to outline, the dbContext holds just the value i want, it is not empty. I have also tryed `valueOf()`, also no change ... i have checked it trough console log, also the value, and the variable type

Comment: By not working, i mean it is not switching between database connections. I have noticed, the issue is present when i first use the active data source and after that i try to use another datasource. In the console log, i see all the variables values in play, also the variable types. Those are not the issue...your english is ok, i have flaws...

Answer (score 0):

See what does `user.getClient_db();` returns. I suspect it's an empty string (`""`)

BTW you're creating a redundant `String` object in `String dbContext = new String();` you can simply do `String dbContext = user.getClient_db();`

Maybe the problem is with your REST method, I'm not sure you can have multiple payloads (e.g `Principal principal` and `User user`. Try removing one and see if that helps

Comment: Just tryed, and still no luck. As u can see, i log also the type and the value of all the variables and can prove, that is not the issue. Always getting the desired data from user.getClient_db() and it is always a java.lang.String, but for some unknown reason, code just wont change db connection - application.properties....

Comment: Is it possible at all, to switch between active data sources inside the same controller after you accessed the first one? It seems to me the answer is no.